# Django check an object has results

Tags: python, django

I want to check if an object returns a value in my views.py this is my code...

```
  city = City.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['autocompleteCity'])
```

So, I was thinking something like this...

```
  city = City.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['autocompleteCity'])

  if city:
     #we have results do something with city object
   else: 
     #no results display error and stop processing form.
```

what is the best way to approach this.

Comment: Note that `get` will raise a `DoesNotExist` if no object is found

Comment: so i could do something like this? if city.DoesNotExist:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get), `.get()` will *always* either return a *single* model, or it will raise one of two exceptions. Simply [put the call in a `try` block, catch the relevant exceptions, and handle appropriately](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
city = City.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data['autocompleteCity'])

if city.count():
   # if you are expecting only one record to be returned, you can access the first record
   # Else you will have to iterate through the result set returned
   print city[0]         
else:
   #no records present
   pass
```